# Pre-Havdalah Melacha

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, havdalah

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bootstrapping problem: havdalah ends shabbat (for one who didn't daven ma'ariv) but lighting the candle is melacha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13922/bootstrapping-problem-havdalah-ends-shabbat-for-one-who-didnt-daven-maariv)

After nightfall before Marriv, or after nightfall for (let's say) women at home who do not say Marriv: Is one allowed to do [melacha](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/610); and when does that allowance come into effect, or what must one do to effect it?