# Praying at the same time

Tags: tefilla, minyan, zechut-merit, shaat-hadechak

Are there any sources (prior to 5780) that discuss the value or lack thereof of isolated individuals praying at the same time?

Comment: Are you asking about specifically when everyone is isolated, or even when an individual is isolated?

Comment: @Alex I took it as  "Everyone agrees to pray together but they aren't in the same location together."

Essentially, Jews agreeing to pray together at an agreed upon time but everyone is in isolation (Like the Coronavirus quarantine) I agree the question needs more clarity.

Comment: Related: "[Can a minyan meet online](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29705/1368)"?

Comment: Previously the discussion has been that an isolated person should pray at the same time that the congregation meets in shul for the minyan. You should make the question clearer as to the exact situation. I have not heard of a case like this year where the shuls are all closed.