# Answering a virtual kaddish?

Tags: halacha, technology, kaddish, amen

If you hear someone saying *kaddish* virtually (such as at a [virtual siyum](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17975/attending-a-siyum-virtually), or a streamed ceremony), should you answer *amen*?

Note that this is talking about when listening live.

Does it make a difference whether you're listening via internet or radio/TV?

Comment: Although the question is now different, I'm pretty sure I saw a duplicate of this now different question somewhere. But I can't find it now, so I am commenting to motivate someone else who may know where that duplicate is.

Comment: I believe the Rivevos Ephraim holds you do,will look it up

Comment: Not a duplicate anymore -- now the question is about live-streaming, instead of recording....though [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12039/5323) to that question deals with this as well

Comment: [@sam](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/40446/759)

Comment: In the 1st season of Homeland Saul Berenson recites Kaddish. Could one answer to that? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: You do say 'Amen' when listening **only** live through a telephone or simulcast (dont think the medium makes a difference). You however arent *yotze* a mitzvah if you do it this way.

Taken from [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=1939&txtSearch=kedusha)

Rabbi Eli Mansour

> Likewise, if a person listens to a live broadcast of a Shiur via
>   telephone, radio or a live feed over the internet, and Kaddish is
>   recited after the Shiur, he should respond to the Kaddish. Since the
>   person hears Kaddish recited live, he should answer. Of course, one
>   does not respond if he hears a recording of Kaddish or of a Beracha.
>   One responds only if he hears the Beracha or Kaddish at the time it is
>   recited, such as via telephone or a live broadcast.

But

> One should not answer “Amen” to a Beracha he hears via telephone or
>   broadcast if he should have recited the Beracha himself. For example,
>   before a person dons his Tallit, he should not call his friend in the
>   synagogue, have him recite the Beracha on his behalf, and then answer
>   “Amen.”

He doesnt mention the exact source, but from the mp3 of the class it sounds like he is reading from a sefer.

Comment: What's the position on internet and radio? Radio seems like phone haclachot would apply, as they're both instant.

Comment: @Scimonster Rabbi Mansour seems to be of the opinion that telephone, radio and internet are all the same in this regard.

Comment: @Scimonster I take issue with the equivalence of a physical distance (outside the shul) to a digital reproduction (the phone/radio/telecast). The voice being heard is being created entirely by the electronic speakers, so there should be no distinction between a "live" recreation or a "replayed" one. I would love to see a further source that justifies the distinctions r' Mansour makes.