# Can you say amein to a bracha from a video?

Tags: halacha, tefillah-betzibbur

I know that you can't be part of a minyan virtually, but does that apply to brachos to? For example, your watching a Rebbe video and the Rebbe gives a bracha to someone should you say amen? (also virtually)

Comment: Are you talking about a livestream video, or prerecorded (or both)? While I don't have a source to link to, one of my Rebbeim during one of the new-normal virtual shiurim took a drink and said that one does say Amen to the Bracha. This was live though, not sure if it would be the same by a recording.

Comment: very closely related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40131/answering-a-virtual-kaddish

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3308/amen-for-recorded-brochos/3309#3309