# Lighting candles on Yom Tov that falls out on Motzei Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, women, yom-tov, havdalah, candle-lighting

Before a woman lights candles for Yom Tov that falls out on Motzei Shabbos does it say anywhere that she needs to say "HaMavdil" first? (Since the kedushas are different -- on Shabbos it was [ossur](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/591/5) to light a fire and now it's muter. Although by a normal Motzei Shabbos this is the same situation perhaps there is some difference between a normal Motzei Shabbos and a Yom Tov that falls out on Motzei Shabbos that.)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13922/759

Comment: Why would this be different from Havdala candle on Motzaei Shabbat?

Comment: @DoubleAA I updated the question. Please don't tell me to explain what the "difference" might be. I'm leaving it up to those who can answer to explain why or why there isn't a difference. That's exactly my question!

Answer (score 3):

The Chayei Adam ([2:8:23](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49395&st=&pgnum=152)) address your point and encourages men to teach their wives (who were generally in charge of lighting the candles and were largely uneducated) to recite ברוך המבדיל בין קודש לקודש before lighting the Yom Tov candles on Saturday night.

Comment: I personally fail to see how this case would be different from the standard Satuday night Havdalah candle, as discussed [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13922/759).