# Preparing for the weekday on Shabbos after nightfall

Tags: halacha, shabbat, motzei-shabbos, hachana-prep-for-weekday

We know there is an issur of hachanah on Shabbos (preparing from Shabbos for the weekday.)

Is there a problem of hachanah (preparing something) "on Shabbos" when it's already after nightfall and no longer "technically" Shabbos. However the person still hasn't made havdallah or "taken out Shabbos".

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13922/759

Answer (score 6):

*Hakhanoth* for the weekday after *Sseth HaKokhavim* ("the appearance of three stars") on *Mossa'ei Shabbath* for the next day is not an *issur* of making preparations for the weekday on *Shabbath*, since it is no longer *Shabbath* but is the first day of the week. There is no such thing as "technically Shabbos" since it is either before or after *Sseth HaKokhavim* - which is itself **the** factor which determines which day it is, NOT the *havdalah* service. Thus, before *sseth* it is *Shabbath waddai* ("Shabbos indeed"), and if it is after *sseth* then it is *eino Shabbath* ("not Shabbos").

However, it ***is*** ***assur le-khatehilah mi-de-rabbanan*** to do *melakhah* before one is *mavdil* either *be-tefillath aravith* or *`al ha-kos* (i.e. recites *havdalah* either in the evening prayer or over a cup).

So, to directly answer your question: Yes, there is a problem with doing *melakhah* (or presumably making *hakhanoth* for the following day) before one recites *havdalah*. It is not, however, a problem because of the *issur* of *hakhanoth* on *Shabbath* for a weekday since it is no longer *Shabbath,* but falls under the general rabbinic prohibition of resuming *melakhah* before the *havdalah* is recited.

However, if you have already recited *ha-Mavdil ben qodhesh le-hol* in your *tefillath `aravith*, then you are allowed to do *melakhah*, as long as you do not eat or drink (with the exception of water) until you also recite *havdalah* on a *kos*.

**See** - *Mishneh Torah, Hilkhoth Shabbath 29:5-7; Arokh HaShulhan OH 299:19*

Comment: isn't it _waddai_?

Comment: All of my Temani and Meqori rabbanim pronounce it with a Dhal Refuyah. I have heard them many times in my own ears. Kol tuv.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I just looked it up in both the Yemenite Edition of the Rambam and all of my dictionaries. The hard Dal is correct. It must be a colloquialism from Arabic since Arabic tends to favor the softer sound. I have changed it to the correct transliteration. Thank you for bringing this to my attention. Kol tuv.