# Source for needing to say “Boruch hamavdil ..” before doing a melacha after Shabbos

Tags: halacha, minhag, shabbat, havdalah, motzei-shabbos

I believe that after Shabbos  one must say “Boruch hamavdil bein kodesh lechol” before doing a melacha. Please can someone supply a source for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Biblical vs. Rabbinical end of Shabbat](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45100/biblical-vs-rabbinical-end-of-shabbat)

Comment: I have edited your question. You can always roll it back if you do not like it.

Comment: Hi Rafael, welcome to the site! Perhaps consider making these two separate questions, one regarding hamavdil and one regarding kissing the mezuza.

Comment: I can't see a clear connection between the first and second questions in this post, so I'm editing out the second question. Feel free to post another post for the second question, or, if you have reason to believe that these two questions could be answered by the same answer, please [edit] that reason into the question post.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate question to the linked question. The link is about the difference between Shabbat from the written Torah and Shabbat according to the Rabbis. If I understand the OP, he is asking for the source of the text Baruch HaMavdil.

Comment: @Rafael Aryeh Welcome. Can you please explain why you believe that the idea of kissing the mezuzah when passing by is associated with the recital of Baruch MaMavdil?

Answer (score 2):

"The Tur, in Orach Chaim 299, brings the opinion of Rabbeinu Asher and the Ba'al Halachot Gedolot that before doing melacha one should say "Hamavdil" with "Shem v'Malchut", that is, in a normative bracha format. Rashi, however, says that only the words "Baruch HaMavdil bein kodesh l'chol" must be said and this is the position adopted by the Shulchan Aruch. This is the common practice." http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=3513

Answer (score 0):

AMAZING......took a while...and I THINK I found something:
http://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/baruch-hamavdil-or-havdala-before-doing-melacha/?hilite=hamavdil#ftn8

I was looking only about a case...or flipping on a switch...or gatting candles...NOT CLEANING THE HOUSE OR INSTALLING A LIGHT FIXTURE....
so:

Other Opinions brought in Admur: There are those opinions [Rabbeinu Yerucham] which rule that o**nly those Melachas which are time consuming and take effort**, such as weaving, writing and chopping wood, **were forbidden by the Sages before saying Havdala or Baruch  Hamavdil .** 
However those Melachas which are performed without any effort, such as lighting a candle or carrying 4 Amos in a public domain, ***are permitted*** **even if they are of Biblical nature, if the proper time of night has arrived, even if one has not yet said  Hamavdil .**

OK...in the Maariv..it is CUSTOMARY (not obligatory) to draw out the VEHU RACHUM...and BARECHU, in order to "add from the mundane to the sacred"..an interesting BACK ENGINEERING of extending Shabbat....bringing MOTZEI into...

That is what was not answered in the other link. We understand by DAYBREAK, Sunday, saying HAMAVDIL is not necessary. I guess the question stands: After "enough" time after Nightfall...3 stars...and an additional as per requirement...if one turns on a light (A NON LABOR INTENSIVE ACT), is there and ISSUR DaRabbanan?